# Barssince to be counting the distance from green triangle to red triangle instead of green triangle to another green

Tags: pine-script

I have a green triangle for longs and red triangle for shorts. Barssince is taking from green triangle to another green triangle and from one red to another red. What I want is barssince to be from a green to a red triangle.

```
fastSMA = sma(close, 15)
slowSMA = sma(close, 45)

enterLong  = crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA)
enterShort = crossunder(fastSMA, slowSMA)

entryPrice = valuewhen(enterLong or enterShort, close, 0)

plot(barsSinceLong, color = color.yellow)
plot(barsSinceShort, color = color.purple)

if barsSinceLong == 0 and barsSinceShort == 0
    c := c_NOT_IN_TRADE
if barsSinceLong > 0 and close < entryPrice
    c := c_LONG_ABOVE_ENTRYPRICE
else if barsSinceLong > 0 and close > entryPrice
    c := c_LONG_BELOW_ENTRYPRICE
else if barsSinceShort > 0 and close > entryPrice
    c := c_SHORT_BELOW_ENTRYPRICE
else if barsSinceShort > 0 and close < entryPrice
    c := c_SHORT_ABOVE_ENTRYPRICE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already plotted both barssince(), so you can see how this function is working, you can do a `cross(barsSinceLong, barsSinceShort)`, this way you will have it from long to short.

Comment: Basically, all I want is to apply barcolor on these candles between the entry and the exit. Longs should be green and shorts red.

Comment: Maybe something like `valuewhen(enterLong, bar_index, 0)` and then comparing between that range, is better?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing it, one of them sounds like: `barcolor(barsSinceLong < barsSinceShort ? color.green : color.red)`, basically it's an if/else statement (if long is the last signal, color the bars with green, otherwise color the bars with red)